# How do I create an expression for sorting dynamically

Tags: c#

I am trying to dynamically create a sorting expression, I am giving the name of the column to sort, which direction to sort, and I know what type of object I am sorting on, but I don't have the IQueryable or anything.

Here is the function I come up with but the syntax is wrong:

```
    private static Expression<Func<Opportunity, Object>> AddSortExpression(string sortOrder)
    {
        Func<Opportunity, Object> func;
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "DATE_CREATED":
                func = Expression.Lambda<Func<Opportunity, Object>>().OrderBy(x => x.DATE_CREATED_UTC);
                break;
            case "DATE_CREATED_DESC":
                func = Expression.Lambda<Func<Opportunity, Object>>().OrderByDescending(x => x.DATE_CREATED_UTC);
                break;
            case "FORECAST_CLOSE_DATE":
                func = Expression.Lambda<Func<Opportunity, Object>>().OrderByDescending(x => x.FORECAST_CLOSE_DATE);
                break;
            case "RESPONSIBLE_USER":
                func = Expression.Lambda<Func<Opportunity, Object>>().OrderBy(x => x.RESPONSIBLE_USER_ID);
                break;
            case "PIPELINE_STAGE":
                func = Expression.Lambda<Func<Opportunity, Object>>().OrderBy(x => x.PIPELINE_ID);
                break;
            default:
                func = Expression.Lambda<Func<Opportunity, Object>>().OrderBy(x => x.OPPORTUNITY_NAME);
                break;
        }
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<Opportunity, Object>>(Expression.Call(func.Method));
    }
```

What is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason why you couldn't pass in the queryable to your method and apply the appropriate orderby call.

```
private static IOrderedQueryable<Opportunity> AddSortExpression(IQueryable<Opportunity> source, OpportunitySortOrder sortOrder)
{
    switch (sortOrder)
    {
    case OpportunitySortOrder.DateCreated:
        return source.OrderBy(x => x.DATE_CREATED_UTC);
    case OpportunitySortOrder.DateCreatedDesc:
        return source.OrderByDescending(x => x.DATE_CREATED_UTC);
    case OpportunitySortOrder.ForecastCloseDate:
        return source.OrderByDescending(x => x.FORECAST_CLOSE_DATE);
    case OpportunitySortOrder.ResponsibleUser:
        return source.OrderBy(x => x.RESPONSIBLE_USER_ID);
    case OpportunitySortOrder.PipelineStage:
        return source.OrderBy(x => x.PIPELINE_ID);
    case OpportunitySortOrder.Name:
    default:
        return source.OrderBy(x => x.OPPORTUNITY_NAME);
    }
}
```